How to handle error of length 0 in r shiny application
After clicking log in (User name: user1, password = pass1) please click on submit button in the left panel.
This shiny app throws error just after logging in and then on clicking submit button error goes off and it works perfectly fine.
For current date the app will display nothing, for any other dates it gives the aggregated mpg from mtcars data set based on selected filters.
This error is probably because I am comparing a null with a value in the if statement.
I am not sure how to handle this and want to get rid of this error as it distracts the user.
library(shinydashboard)
library(shiny)
library(shinyauthr)
library(dplyr)
library(DT)

# dataframe that holds usernames, passwords and other user data
user_base <- tibble::tibble(
user = c("user1", "user2"),
password = sapply(c("pass1", "pass2"), sodium::password_store),
permissions = c("admin", "standard"),
name = c("User One", "User Two")
)

ui <- dashboardPage(
dashboardHeader(title = "Hi",tags$li(class = "dropdown", style = "padding: 8px;", 
shinyauthr::logoutUI("logout"))),
dashboardSidebar(uiOutput("tarikh_1"),
               uiOutput("cyls"),
               submitButton("submit")),
dashboardBody(
shinyauthr::loginUI(id = "login"),
uiOutput("tabs")
))

server <- function(input,output,session){
data <- mtcars

output$tarikh_1 <- renderUI({
req(credentials()$user_auth)
dateInput("date1","Date_1",value = NULL)
})

output$cyls <- renderUI({
req(credentials()$user_auth)
selectInput("cyl","select cylinder",choices = c('4','6','8'),multiple = TRUE)
})

credentials <- shinyauthr::loginServer(
id = "login",
data = user_base,
user_col = user,
pwd_col = password,
sodium_hashed = TRUE,
log_out = reactive(logout_init())
)  

# Logout to hide
logout_init <- shinyauthr::logoutServer(
id = "logout",
active = reactive(credentials()$user_auth)
)  

table_1 <- reactive({
if(input$date1== Sys.Date()){
  return()
  
}else{      
  f <- input$cyl
  
  grps <- c('cyl')[c(!is.null(f))]
  print(grps)
  
  grps <- paste(grps,collapse = ",")
  print(grps)
  
  
  if(grps ==""){        
    data %>% summarise(Average_mileage = sum(mpg))
    
  }else{
    print(f)
    if(is.null(f)) f <- c("4","6","8")
    data %>% filter(cyl %in% f) %>% group_by(cyl) %>% summarise(Average_mileage = sum(mpg))
   }}})

  output$non_bin <- renderDataTable({
  table_1()
  })

output$tabs <- renderUI({
req(credentials()$user_auth)
tabsetPanel(type = "tab",
            tabPanel("Aggregate_calculation",dataTableOutput("non_bin")))
})}

shiny::shinyApp(ui, server)


If you use req(input$date1) - as you have done elsewhere, immediately before the if statement, you should probably be OK.

@Limey It worked...Thanks a ton. It seems Shiny take null values at the start up even when default values are assigned to the variables

Yes it does. As explained in the online doc and elsewhere.
